# Is there a way to make a script to update chromium instead of downloading and extracting it every time

Tags: windows, google-chrome, powershell, chromium

I am wondering if there is a way to make a script (For windows) to automatically download and extract chromium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer. Open powershell editor and copy and paste this.

```
Write-Output 'Updating Chromium'
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
cd $env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Temp
Write-Output 'Downloading'
Invoke-WebRequest https://download-chromium.appspot.com/dl/Win_x64?type=snapshots -OutFile 
$env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\Chromium.zip
Remove-Item "$env:userprofile\Local Apps\chrome-win" -Recurse
Write-Output 'Unpacking Files'
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}

Unzip "$env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\Chromium.zip" "$env:userprofile\Local Apps"
Remove-Item '$env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\Chromium.zip'

$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Chrome.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "$env:userprofile\Local Apps\chrome.exe"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

If there are any problems with the script, let me know

Comment: Well, this `Remove-Item `'$env:userprofile\Local Apps\chrome-win' -Recurse` is not valid syntax. You are using single quotes and that will not expand the `$env:UserProfile` variable. It should be this. `Remove-Item "$env:userprofile\Local Apps\chrome-win" -Recurse`